# What can I say about a bipartite graph with minimum degree $d$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, optimization, induction

If a bipartite graph is $d$-regular, then there are $d$ disjoint perfect matchings.

In the $d$-regular case we can iteratively remove a perfect matching, resulting in a $d-1$-regular graph and repeat.

In my graph, all vertices have degree at least $d$. How can we prove that there are $d$ disjoint edge covers? Is it possible to reduce this to the $d$-regular case?

This is a known result but I am ideally looking for a constructive proof or iterative proof, or one which reduces it to the $d$-regular case.

Comment: You can't reduce it because it's not true. In the case $d=1$, it would mean that any bipartite graph with no isolated vertices has a perfect matching; but counterexamples are easy to find (even among bipartite graphs with two equal-sized parts).

Comment: In the question I state that I want to prove the existence of $d$ disjoint edge covers.

Comment: @darijgrinberg thanks for mentioning this. Do you know what additional constraints must be imposed so that there is in fact a perfect matching for a bipartite graph with equal sized parts with a minimum degree d > 1?